# What is the scope of atomic_thread_ fence?

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-barriers

*Please understand that I am not from an English-spoken country, so if you couldn’t understand my question, please let me know so I can explain in other words. J

Is the fence scope of atomic_thread_fence a scope unit that has been designated as “{}”?

For example,
**MainActivity C++**

```
//section A
if(A == 1)
{
   //section B
   atomic_thread_fence(..);
   //section C
}
//section D
```

Regarding to the above code, I’d like to know if the fence is applied only in the section B and section C, or it gets applied in other sections too.

Thanks.~

Comment: One question per post please.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Fences have no notion of scope. Instead, they have the notion of loads / stores that are *before* the fence, and loads / stores that are *after* the fence : in your example, loads / stores *before* include those of sections B and A (and before that). Loads and stores *after* the fence include those of sections C and D (and after that).

And the fence will have an effect only when `A == 1` (i.e, a fence that is located in a branch that is not taken will not have any side effect).

Comment: Do you mean "everything" means all call stacks where there are variables with fence applied? @Olivier Shon

Comment: @grx00 what I meant by "everything" is "every load and store". I'll update my answer to make it clearer.